# jplist default where condition with default order by php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, jplist

**this is my html page everything is working fine except default where condition with default order by, please have a look at my code**

*html frontend page*

This is my html code everything is loading but i want to default ordering when i use where and order by other sorting is not working.

```
<div class="row product-data">
<div class="row">
    <!-- ajax content here -->
    <!--<div class="list box text-shadow" style="margin: 30px 0 0;"></div>-->
    <div class="list" style="margin: 30px 0 0;"></div>
</div>
```

Now this is my server file

protected
        function getData() {

```
        $items = null;

        $query = "SELECT * FROM ".DB_TABLE.
        " WHERE status=0";

        if ($this - > filter - > filterQuery) {
            $query. = " ".$this - > filter - > filterQuery.
            " ";
        }

        //get queries / fields              
        if ($this - > sorting - > sortQuery) {
            $query. = " ".$this - > sorting - > sortQuery.
            " ";
        }

        //error_log(print_r($this->filter->filterQuery));

        if ($this - > pagination - > paginationQuery) {
            $query. = " ".$this - > pagination - > paginationQuery.
            " ";
        }

        if (count($this - > filter - > preparedParams) > 0) {

            $stmt = $this - > db - > prepare($query);
            $stmt - > execute($this - > filter - > preparedParams);
            $items = $stmt - > fetchAll();
        } else {
            $items = $this - > db - > query($query);
        }

        return $items;
    }
```

please help me out